# Inherit model and rendering parameters both in Sitecore MVC view using Glass Mapper

Tags: sitecore, sitecore7, glass-mapper, sitecore-mvc, sitecore8

I am trying to access the rendering parameters for a particular view rendering, which also has the model bound to it, something like this:

```razor
@inherits Glass.Mapper.Sc.Web.Mvc.GlassView<IPageBase>
```

I was reading the tutorial for the rendering parameters on glass.lu - http://www.glass.lu/Mapper/Sc/Tutorials/Tutorial23 - that I should be to inherit the parameters template the same way:

```razor
@inherits Glass.Mapper.Sc.Web.Mvc.GlassView<INews_Rendering_Parameters>
```

But I can't bind both of them - so how is this done?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `GlassView` class also exposes the `GetRenderingParameters` method, so you can use that in your Razor view to access the strongly typed rendering parameters:

```razor
@inherits Glass.Mapper.Sc.Web.Mvc.GlassView<IPageBase>

var parameters = GetRenderingParameters<INews_Rendering_Parameters>();
```

then access your properties as normal, e.g. @Editable(model, x => x.Title) or @parameters.MyProperty

It's mentioned in the tutorial at the end of Sitecore MVC but perhaps the example is not very clear.